# Arbitrary nested type

Tags: haskell

I tried to come up with a way of creating a arbitrarily deep nested type where each instance depends on the type of it's parent, but I couldn't come up with any solution.

I was thinking about something like a type `T` with two type variables, where the second is itself a `T` which first type variable depends on its parent.

```hs
data T a b = T (a -> b) (T (b -> c) (T (c -> d) ...))
```

I know that in theory every type variable should appear on the left and right side,  and I don't know if this is even possible at all, but I guess that there is some way of making this work.

My experience with GHC extensions like `GADTs` and `RankNTypes` is very limited but as far as I know this would be a usecase for those?

Comment: "every type variable should appear on the left and right side" - existential types (`ExistentialQuantification`) do not appear in the result type, `data T a b = forall c. T c (c -> (a, b))` here `c` is existential

Comment: What's the actual goal here? Like, what problem do you hope to solve by creating arbitrarily nested types this way? There are several things kind of like this that exist and solve narrow problems. If you could explain your goal, we could provide an answer that actually helps instead of random guessing.

Comment: I wonder if @Fabus1184 is looking for a non-regular (nested) datatype like [`FunList`](https://twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/non-regular1) where each `More` constructor adds a function argument to the argument of `Done`.

Comment: Are you trying to build a type for something like a lens which has a start type and an end type and internally a series of intermediate types?

Comment: yes exactly, like concatenated functions, the start type would be some `a -> b` and the end type would be `z -> IO ()` and i would be able to compose everything together to `a -> IO ()` without the intermediate types being represented in the start / end types